# Force android bluetooth discovery on

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there a way to force the bluetooth adapter to be discoverable? Like the BluetoothAdapter.Enable() method?

I know about the BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE but it show a dialog to the user.

I want to do this to make it easier for the user to use the application - so they can set a Auto connect setting to true... and then it wan't ask these questions again. But I don't know how to get around the dialog?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that without user interaction.  You can autoconnect to a previously paired bluetooth device but you can't make the device discoverable without user interaction I believe for security reasons.